# Symfony : Sonata admin custom List Fields URL

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

After looking in the documentation : 
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/field_types.html

I need your help because i want to go a little further in customization and it's not indicated how to do in the documentation.

With this :

```
        ->add('hash', "url",  array(
              'label' => 'HashCode',
              'header_style' => 'width: 20%; text-align: center',
              'row_align' => 'center',
              'route' => array(
                  'name' => 'cr_whiz_home',
                  'identifier_parameter_name' => 'id[]'
              )
          ))
```

I can generate this URL for example:

http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/home?id%5B%5D=27

But what I search is to change 27 at the end, because Sonata Admin take automatically id of the entity. I want to take another, the HashCode, i think there is a parameter to change it, but I didn't find it.

Can you help me ? Thank's !

Comment: why don't you change `identifier_parameter_name` to `HashCode`?

Comment: That doesn't work, I tried and nothing append. Even hash_parameter_name or something else.

Comment: Not possible yet, you'll have to use a template: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3582